# Enable Lightning button after file upload in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I have a lwc page where users can upload files in an object.
Now, I have a requirement where the import button need to be enabled only after the file is uploaded succesfully. Till then, it has to be greyed out.

Below is the my lwc code:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-page-header__row">
            <div class="slds-page-header__col-title">
                <div class="slds-media">
                    <div class="slds-media__figure">
          <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-case" title="opportunity">
            <svg class="slds-icon slds-page-header__icon" aria-hidden="true">
              <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opportunity"></use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">opportunity</span>
          </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                        <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                            <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                                <h1>
                                    <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="File Import">File Import</span>
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <Lightning-card>
        <div style="width: max-content;margin-left: 20px;">

            1. Download Sample CSV File <br/> <br/>
            <div>
                <a href={FileUrl}
                   download={FileUrl}
                   target="_blank" >
                    <button>DOWNLOAD SAMPLE CSV FILE</button>

                </a>
            </div>

            <br/> <br/>
            2. Upload CSV File to Insert
            <div style="width: max-content;margin-left: 20px;">
                <input type="file" multiple accept=".csv" class="slds-p-around_small"/>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <lightning-button
                        variant="brand"
                        label="Import"
                        onclick={readCSVFile}
                        class="slds-p-around_small"
                        >
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
            <div><lightning-formatted-text value={statusMessage} ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
        </div>
    </Lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import executeBulkInsert from '@salesforce/apex/FileUploadController.executeBulkInsert';
import TRAILHEAD_CHARACTERS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/SampleFiles';
export default class BulkInsert extends LightningElement {


    value = '';

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }

    @api sobjectName = 'Case';
    statusMessage = '';
    FileUrl = 'Sample CSV File' + '/SampleFile/BulkLoad.pdf';
    readCSVFile() {

        console.log('readFiles');
        [...this.template.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files].forEach(async file => {
            try {
                const csvResult = await this.load(file);
                console.log('csvResult ' + csvResult);
                // Process the CSV here
                if(csvResult != null) {
                    executeBulkInsert({ csvResult: csvResult, sobjectName: this.sobjectName })
                        .then((result) => {
                            this.statusMessage = result;
                            console.log('final result', this.statusMessage);
                            this.error = undefined;
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log('error from apex: ' + error);
                            this.error = error;
                        });
                }
            } catch(e) {
                // handle file load exception
            }
        });
    }
    async load(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            console.log('file: ' + file);
            reader.onload = function() {
                resolve(reader.result);
                console.log('resolve: ' + reader.result);
            };
            reader.onerror = function() {
                reject(reader.error);
                console.log('reject: ' + reader.error);
            };
            console.log('abcd',reader.result);
            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }
}
```

can anyone please suggest any changes so that i can enable the import button only after the file is succesfully uploaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a tracked variable `inputFiles` to read the uploaded files.
2. Use a getter to return the boolean if atleast 1 file is selected.
3. Use that getter variable for dynamically managing `disabled` attribute of button.

HTML:

```
2. Upload CSV File to Insert
<div style="width: max-content;margin-left: 20px;">
    <input type="file" multiple class="slds-p-around_small" onchange={fileSelected} />
</div><br>
<div>
    <lightning-button
                        variant="brand"
                        label="Import"
                        onclick={readCSVFile}
                        class="slds-p-around_small"
                        disabled={disableImport}>
    </lightning-button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
@track inputFiles;

fileSelected(event) {
    this.inputFiles = event.target;
}

get disableImport() {
    return !this.inputFiles || this.inputFiles.files.length === 0;
}
```

Comment: the js code is not getting saved. While HTML is saved without any error, JS code is not getting saved to Salesforce. Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: what error are you getting in JS file?

Comment: My bad...wire and track are not imported in js file. When I included that, it is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the import button as long as there is no file uploaded.

```
fileSelected(event) {
    this.inputFiles = (event.target.files.length === 0) ? false : event.target;
}
```